# Excel shorting and writing blank column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to find and write the blank value from first non blank column to the blank cell. for example:-

```
Column A
----------------
-Blank cell- 
-Blank cell-
abc
abd
-Blank cell-
-Blank cell-
-Blank cell-
xyz
ycz
```

My Result should be

```
 Column B
-----------
abc
abc
abc
abd
xyz
xyz
xyz
xyz
ycz
```

there are more than 25K entries with me and blank cells are not specified. Can someone please help me with this. any Excel formula or script will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First select the cells in the column:

[image]

2. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and click on 'Special...':

[image]

3. Select 'Blanks':

[image]

4. Click OK:

[image]

5. From here, don't do anything except press the keys to type the formula: `=A2` (<kbd>=</kbd> then arrow down key):

[image]

6. When the formula is done, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

7. Optional: Copy the whole column and paste as values to remove the formulae.

Answer (score 1):

Using a macro:

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then LastCheck = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = LastCheck
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: awesome reply Xabi! I loved this macro. I have one more task could you help me out with it?

Comment: If I am able to help I would love to be of assistance... :)

Comment: I want to Copy and paste first non blank cell to the adjacent  non blank column.

Comment: stackoverflow is not letting me post another question untill 90 min.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `IF` can do this.

`B1 = IF(A1="",B2,A1)`

Fill the formula in all column B.